# Linq to SQL: How to join on no field i.e. cartesian join

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

How can I make a Linq To SQL join on multiple tables where 1 table should produce a Cartesian product.

To shed some more light, here is a sample of the SQL query.

```
SELECT Table1.MyField, Setup.SomeField
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.SomeField = Table2.SomeField, Setup
```

My Linq to SQL are like:

```
var q = from t1 in db.Table1
        join t2 in db.Table2 on t1.SomeField equals t2.SomeField
        join setup in db.Setup 
        select new {t1.MyField, setup.SomeField};
```

I'm getting an error on the last join that `Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SelectMany` rather than a `Join` to perform a Cartesian Product.

In query syntax that would be:

```
var query = from t1 in db.Table1
    from t2 in db.Table2
    select new {t1, t2};
```

Comment: Thanks, but not sure where to use the SelectMany?

Comment: @user1208908 Where you want to perform a Cartesian Product with another collection.

Answer (score 1):

This will also do:

```
var q = from t1 in db.Table1
        join t2 in db.Table2 on t1.SomeField equals t2.SomeField
        from setup in db.Setup 
        select new {t1.MyField, setup.SomeField};
```